# image resize and add watermark in codeigniter at same time

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php
$config["image_library"] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = $image_org;
$config['new_image'] = $image_thumb;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config["width"] = $width;
$config["height"] = $height;
$config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$config['wm_overlay_path'] = './images/logo.png';
$config['wm_opacity'] = 50;
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->watermark();
?>
```

i need to perform image resize and add watermark in same  function, but either of resize or watermark only works ?

Comment: what PHP version are you using? please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html

Watermarking is only available using the GD/GD2 library. 
In addition, even though other libraries are supported, GD is required in order for the script to calculate the image properties. The image processing, however, will be performed with the library you specify.

Try using GD, ImageMagick, NetPBM in `$config["image_library"]="GD"; //`

You will have to install PHP GD2 Library on your machine.

For ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd && sudo service apache2 restart
```

For windows

you'll include the GD2 DLL `php_gd2.dll` as an extension in `php.ini`.